# How can I create a default object in Javascript using a schema?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I would like to create a default object, using a function, based on a schema that I have in my project.

Here is the schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const HoursPerCreditSchema = new Schema({

    hours: {type: Number, required: true},
})

module.exports = HourPerCredit = mongoose.model('hoursPerCredit', HoursPerCreditSchema)
```

this is what I am trying :

```
defaultHourPerCredit = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{

        const newHourPerCredit = new HourPerCredit({
            hours: 4
        });

        resolve(newHourPerCredit);
    });
};


module.exports = {
    defaultHourPerCredit
};
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
var hpc = hoursPerCreditFunctions.defaultHourPerCredit();
console.log(JSON.stringify(hpc));
```

this is what is output:

```
{}
```

Comment: `hpc` is the `Promise`, not an instance of `HourPerCredit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok... I was just a little bit off (thanks for the hint  https://stackoverflow.com/users/1541563/patrick-roberts )

```
defaultHourPerCredit = () => {
    const newHourPerCredit = new HourPerCredit({
        hours: 4
    });
    return newHourPerCredit;
};
```